# pthread_join() is not working

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm experimenting with posix threads and just can't figure out the problem I'm facing right now.

Blink1 and Blink2 get called in two threads, Blink1 is supposed to exit and have main join it, after that Blink2 is supposed to get  terminated by main.

What happens is that Blink1 does its 5 time loop but Blink2 just stays infinite, the 'printf("joined\n");' in main never gets called.

What am I missing? Once again too stupid to read the manual?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int i = 0;

void *blink1(){
    int j;
    for ( j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        //activate
        printf("blink1: i = %d ON\n", i);
        sleep(1);
        //deactivate
        printf("blink1: i = %d OFF\n", i);
        sleep(1);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *blink2(){
    while (1){
        //activate
        printf("blink2: i = %d ON\n", i);
        sleep(1);
        //deactivate
        printf("blink2: i = %d OFF\n", i);
        sleep(1);
        i++;
    }
}

int main(){
    pthread_t thrd1, thrd2;

    //start threads
    pthread_create(&thrd1, NULL, &blink1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thrd1, NULL, &blink2, NULL);

    //output pid + tid
    printf("PID: %d ; TID1: %lu ; TID2: %lu\n", getpid(), thrd1, thrd2);

    //wait for thread 1
    pthread_join(thrd1, NULL);
    printf("joined\n");

    //terminte thread 2
    pthread_kill(thrd2, 15);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you notice that `thrd1` is used twice? That means it's overwritten, so you're actually joining on your second thread, which never ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are *reusing* the thread identifier `thrd1` for creating the the second thread. That means you can't *join* with thread 1.

You are effectively waiting for the 2nd thread. Since, the 2nd thread runs infinitely, main thread won't get a chance to execute the `pthread_kill()` statement.

Comment: I discovered this because of a compile warning. @Siraja, make sure you use a high warning level when you compile.

Comment: wow, i've been reading the man pages of create join and kill up and down for half an hour and in the end it's just a stupid copy-paste error.. thank you very much!

Comment: @Siraja Also, you have another subtle problem. There's a *data race* (which is *undefined*) in the access to variable `i` as it's accessed by the two threads with any synchronization. I would also suggest to not hard code signal numbers (15) and instead use the respective macro from signal.h

Answer (score 3):

typo:

```
//start threads
pthread_create(&thrd1, NULL, &blink1, NULL);
pthread_create(&thrd1, NULL, &blink2, NULL);
```

probably should be:

```
 //start threads
pthread_create(&thrd1, NULL, &blink1, NULL);
pthread_create(&thrd2, NULL, &blink2, NULL);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you use `thrd1` twice when creating threads.

In fact, your join is waiting for the second thread.